# WebSphere MQ Configuration issues

Tags: java, jms, websphere, ibm-mq, mq

getting below error after i configure MQ connection factory.

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSQueueConnectionFactoryHandle incompatible with com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory

my code snippet where the exception is pointing to :

> String queueConnectionJndi = props.getProperty(queueConnection + MQ_CONN);
>   queueConnectionFactory = MQQueueConnectionFactory)initialContext.lookup(queueConnectionJndi);

I am not able to find out the root cause of this.

can any body please help me on this, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this link help:http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21238470

Comment: @Shashi : i tried using that way as well still i got same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the MQ jars which WAS is using and my application using are different so this problem occured. when i corrected the classpath it is resolved. sorry for the trouble, thanks for the help.

Comment: Solved a similar issue by excluding *geronimo* jars from ActiveMQ dependencies.

Comment: @srini : could you please tell me where can I find these WAS jars for MQ. there are so many jar files inside WAS and I am confused. Could you please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to be sure without more context, but it looks like this method call:

```
initialContext.lookup(queueConnectionJndi);
```

is returning an object of type com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSQueueConnectionFactoryHandle which cannot be cast to com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory.

Can you provide more context?

Answer (score 0):

This [Post on old nabble](http://old.nabble.com/Axis2-JMSListener-on-Websphere-td15165852.html) sounds like a similar issue and may help you out.

Specifically the final response talks about removing any `jms.jar` file(s) that may be in your deployed WAR. Check your `WEB-INF/lib`. Certain jars are provided by the Websphre container and shouldn't be including them in your WAR.

This [Post on the spring fourm](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?62562-JMS-Spring-JSF-on-WAS-Class-loader-issues) also indicates issues of this nature caused by jars included in the classpath that shouldn't be there

Remove any of the following if you find them...

```
naming.jar
providerutil.jar
jndi.jar
jms.jar
mq.jar
websphere.jar
```

Comment: How complex is your deployable EAR? does it contain multiple JARs and WARs, or only the one WAR file?

Comment: it contain multiple JARs and WARs

Answer (score 0):

Can you rewrite your code to use JMS standard ([ConnectionFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/ConnectionFactory.html) or [QueueConnectionFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/QueueConnectionFactory.html))instead of a Websphere MQ specific implementation class?  That way you won't be tying your app to Websphere MQ and porting it to an alternative MQ implementation would be easier...

i.e.

```
import javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory;
...

queueConnectionFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory)initialContext.lookup(jndiName);
```

Comment: i have tried this but in this scenario i am getting Some other exception like Name not found.

Comment: what is the name that you are using and are you referencing it through web.xml?

Answer (score 0):

I went through a lot of trial and error to find the answer (the answer to my question at least). I hope this solution will solve your issues too. As mentioned from another post excluding the jms library works. But how do you exclude the jms library and still be able to compile the code? That was something no one seems to have mentioned. The solution to that is to make the scope for the jms library to "provided" (if you are using Maven or Gradle).

As mentioned somewhere:

"Provided means that you need the JAR for compiling, but at run time there is already a JAR provided by the environment so you don't need it packaged with your app. For a web app, this means that the JAR file will not be placed into the WEB-INF/lib directory."

So in your pom.xml add/update these:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.jms-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Hopefully this can be helpful to those who have been frustrated by the lack of answers from the Internet.

Remove all the ibm libraries. They are useless. Once you deploy onto Websphere, it will use its libraries anyways.